# Mostrar en mi datagridview datos con procedimiento almacenado con parametros tipo fecha? C#

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, windows-forms

Me gustaria pedirles su ayuda, tengo mi proyecto por modelo de capas y quiero mostrar en mi datagridview los datos ejecutando un procedimiento almacenado para que muestre solo los datos por un rango de fechas pero al momento de ejecutar mi proyecto no me muestra nada, puedo preguntarles en que estoy mal o que me falta, les dejo mi codigo:

CapaDatos:

```
    public SqlConnection AbrirConexion()
    {
        if (conexion.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conexion.Open();
        return conexion;
    }

    public SqlConnection CerrarConexion()
    {
        if (conexion.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            conexion.Close();
        return conexion;            
    }

    SqlDataReader leer;
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();  

    public DataTable Report32(string FechaIn, string FechaFin)
    {
        //Transact SQL
        comando.Connection = conexion.AbrirConexion2();
        comando.CommandText = "dbo.udpM12953_Reporte032";
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StarDate", FechaIn);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", FechaFin);
        leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
        table.Load(leer);
        conexion.CerrarConexion2();
        return table;
    }
```

CapaNegocio:

```
    public DataTable MostrarReport(string FechaIn, string FechaFin)
    {
        DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
        objetoCD.Report32(FechaIn, FechaFin);
        return tabla;
    }
```

CapaPresentacion:

```
    private void MostrarReport32()
    {
        CN_HeadCount objeto = new CN_HeadCount();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = objeto.MostrarReport(txtFechaInicial.Text, txtFechaFinal.Text);  

    }
```

Porfavor si me ayudan a revisar que hice mal o que me falta les agradeceria mucho :)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No termino de entender tu problema, si tenes dos cadenas de conexion entonces te conectas a dos bases... que es exactamente lo que queres hacer?

Comment: @gbianchi como mencione me gustaria mostrar los datos de mi tabla de la segunda base de datos por medio de un procedimiento almacenado con dos parametros, ya habia hecho la segunda cadena de conexion pero al ejecutarla no me mostraba nada mi datagridview pero tampoco tenia error, por lo que pense que no estaba bien trabajar asi dos bases de datos

Comment: sigo sin entender.. tu sp donde esta? que tiene que ver con dos bases de datos? tu sp esta en una base y vos queres traer datos de otra? no queda claro el problema...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sé si es el caso, pero por el código que has mostrado parece alguna mala praxis o errores que podrían haber derivado que no se te cargaran los datos y te devolviera null.
Publico el código editado:

CapaDatos:

```
 public SqlConnection AbrirConexion()
    {
        if (conexion.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conexion.Open();
        return conexion;
    }

public SqlConnection CerrarConexion()
{
    if (conexion.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        conexion.Close();
    return conexion;            
}


public DataTable Report32(string FechaIn, string FechaFin)
{
  SqlDataReader leer;
  DataTable table = new DataTable();// si devuelves el datatable tienes que crear el objeto cada vez que llames la función, si no el objeto cambia de datos únicamente, puede llegar a generar errores.
  SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();  

    //Transact SQL
    comando.Connection = conexion.AbrirConexion2();
    comando.CommandText = "dbo.udpM12953_Reporte032";
    comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StarDate", FechaIn);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", FechaFin);
    leer = comando.ExecuteReader();
    table.Load(leer);
    conexion.CerrarConexion2();
    return table;
}
```

CapaNegocio:

```
   public DataTable MostrarReport(string FechaIn, string FechaFin)
    {
      
        DataTable tabla =  objetoCD.Report32(FechaIn, FechaFin); //devuelve el datatable lleno si no creabas un objeto vacío a secas, probablemente el error que hacía que no se te cargaran los datos
        return tabla;
    }
```

Capa Presentación:

```
 private void MostrarReport32()
    {
        CN_HeadCount objeto = new CN_HeadCount();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = objeto.MostrarReport(txtFechaInicial.Text, txtFechaFinal.Text);  

    }
```

Comment: Tuviste toda la razon, ya sabia que en algun lado tenia algun error pero aun soy inexperto en esto y no sabia porque era y como habias dicho era primero porque no creaba el objeto cada vez que llamaba la funcion y la otra como tambien dijiste era porque mandaba el datatable vacio, te agradesco mucho tu ayuda :)